# Finding the sequence that maximizes a constrained sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization, summation

Let $0 < a < 1$ and let $S_k$ be a unknown sequence of such that $S_k > 0$ and

$$
S_n  + S_{n-1} + \ldots + S_1 = C = constant.
$$

What should be $S_k$ so that the sum

$$
S_n + aS_{n-1} + a^2 S_{n-2} + \ldots + a^{n-1}S_1
$$

is maximized? I am looking for an expression of $S_k$ in terms of $a, k$ and $C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum.

Note that

$$S_n + aS_{n-1} + a^2 S_{n-2} + \ldots + a^{n-1}S_1 \leq S_n + S_{n-1} +  S_{n-2} + \ldots + S_1 =C $$

with equality if and only if $S_n=C, S_1,.., S_{n-1}=0$.

Setting $S_n=C-\epsilon, S_1=..=S_{n-1}= \frac{\epsilon}{n-1}$ yields a sum greater than $C-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a \lt 1, a^i \lt 1$.  You can't maximize the sum, but want $S_n$ as close to $C$ as possible and all the other $S's$ as small as possible.